# tflite flutter application gives only one output

Tags: flutter, tensorflow-lite

While working with `tflite` in flutter the output I get is
`output = [{confidence: 0.8115850687026978, index: 90, label: cynoglossum lanceolatum}]`

and it's obviously seen that there is only one put, the model I am using trained from Teachable machine.
How do I get multiple outputs from the image being recognized

Answer (score 0):

When you run your model there is an attribute numResults is defaulted to 1. You can change to get more results.

```
var recognitions = await Tflite.runModelOnImage(
  path: image.path,
  numResults: 1,
  threshold: 0.05,
  imageMean: 127.5,
  imageStd: 127.5,
);
```

Comment: Do you know where I can find documentation describing each of the parameters for runModelOnImage?

Comment: Probably you have already visited, but you can check https://pub.dev/documentation/tflite/latest/ maybe you can find it useful.

Comment: Unfortunately non of the parameters are described on that page.